# Storing HealthKit data in my app

Tags: ios, ios8, healthkit

Looking at the guidelines for HealthKit and not sure if I can store data from HealthKit in my app.  Is an app allowed to copy data from HealthKit to store in its own data store?  My worry is that if a user wants to stop using HealthKit that he/she would lose the data in my app.  I won't sync with iCloud or anything.    Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll find the HealthKit guidelines from Apple here: [Apple HealthKit Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#healthkit)

You can store the data also after they revoke the permission. You are also allowed to save them on your own server, but not in the iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Once a user accept your App for sharing the data he/she will not be able to change the permission back to normal. thats the draw back till now and yes you can store the data in your App but uploading this data on cloud is allowed

Rgds
Prashant kaushik